# WPF XAML Parse Exception occured Error?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

```
 <Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            x:Class="AFICController.EULA"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:res="clr-namespace:AFICController.Resources"
            Title="{x:Static res:Strings.WizardWelcomeWindow_Title}"
            Width="800"
            Height="600"  
            WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
            Icon="/AFICController;Component/Resources/Images/att_icon.ico"
            ResizeMode="NoResize">
```

I am working on a C# WPF Applcation i am implementing it using MVVM .My Application shows splash screen at first which appears fine but after that i want EULA(End user license agreement) Window when i try to execute it shows an exception as "XAML Parse Exception "Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension' threw an exception" by locating towards the above code.

Following is my C# code from where i am calling EULA..Please help me as i have tried my all ways in removing this exception.?

```
class App : Application
{
[STAThread()]
static void Main()
{
  Splasher.Splash = new SplashScreen();
  Splasher.ShowSplash();

  Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;

  for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1);
  }

  Splasher.CloseSplash();
  new App();
}
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public App()
{

  App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new       Uri(@"\Resources\Dictionary\ATTColors.xaml", UriKind.Relative) });

  App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(@"\Resources\Dictionary\AppButton.xaml", UriKind.Relative) });

  Console.WriteLine("EULA Opened");
  StartupUri = new System.Uri("EULA.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

  //StartupUri = new System.Uri("View/WizardDialog.xaml", UriKind.Relative);


  Run();
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Given your error:

> "XAML Parse Exception "Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension' threw an exception"

I think your problems lies in this line:

```
Title="{x:Static res:Strings.WizardWelcomeWindow_Title}"
```

which is where the `StaticExtension` is used.

Make sure that your `Strings.resx` is public by going to its properties and checking that Custom Tool is set to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` (and not `ResXFileCodeGenerator`, which is the default) - you can either directly edit it there or through the `Access Modified` combobox in the designer when you open the resources file.

Comment: But it generates another error as follows : "The invocation of the constructor on type 'AFICController.EULA' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception."

Comment: Anyone have idea about this ??

Comment: You should debug the constructor of your `AFICController.EULA` Window. The exception probably offers you some more information. If you can't solve it, I'd suggest you post a new question with the relevant code and exception.

Comment: Or you can change "Access Modifier" to "Public" when *.resx is opened in designer, which has same effect but (at least to me) involves less "magic".

Comment: @sluki can't believe I missed that. Editing the answer right away, thanks.

Comment: You saved the day. Thank you.